# Swift ObjectMapper: toJSONString for a dictonary containing mappable Object

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I would like to to get the json string for the following Dictionary, but I don't know what is the appropriate way to do so.

```
/* For example, I have a Dictionary contains a set of users and I want to get the JSONString of it. */

class User: Mappable {
    // some other implemenation ...
}

/* in some other class, e.g MyService.swift */
func generateString() -> String {
    let user1 = User()
    let user2 = User()

    // some other implemenation ...

    let seatDict: [String:User] = [
       "1A": user1,
       "1B": user2,
       // some other implemenation ...
       // some other implemenation ...
    ]

    // here i would like to return the JsonString of my seatDict
    let result: String = ... // how to do it?
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using the `Mapper` class.

```
...
// here i would like to return the JsonString of my seatDict
let jsonDict = Mapper<User>().toJSONDictionary(seatDict)
let result: String? = Mapper<User>.toJSONString(jsonDict as Any, prettyPrint: false)
return result
```

Keep in mind that `toJSONString` can return nil if serialisation fails - so you need to handle that somehow in your application. That's why I changed `result` to be optional

Comment: if I use your above approach, I would get a json string like `"{list: {"1A" : { ... } }"` which is not what I want. I want a jonstring like: `{"1A": {...}, "1B":{...}, ...}`

Comment: I modified the answer

Comment: Is that what you wanted ?